# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'longitude'

Tags: pandas, data-mining, data, data-cleaning

I'm trying to get the location longitude of a address using geopy.
normally this works completely fine.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

# Initialize Nominatim API
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="MyApp")

def loc(x):
        location = geolocator.geocode(x)
        return location.longitude

loc("RK Mission Road Gopibag Motijheel Dhaka")
```

but when I pass the data column it gives this unknown error **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'longitude'**.
Found 0 missing or nan values in the data column.

```
df["Longitude"]=df['Location'].apply(loc)
```

Comment: where did you load `df` from? Please provide code. Basically the error says (at least one) `df['Location']` is `None` so I would start by doing a quick check on all 'Location' values.

Comment: i have loaded the data from kaggle(https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/taeefnajib/house-rent-in-dhaka-city) . I have checked the df for nan values 'df.isna().sum()' but did not found any  **Location     0
Area sqft    0
Bed          0
Bath         0
Price        0**  @lpounng

Comment: I see. Then the problem is likely from `geolocator.geocode(x)`, where an `x` (`df['Location']`) is assigned `None`. Quick check: add a check in the `loc` method, if `location` is `None`, print out `x`. This geo-location `x` failed to be geocoded.

Comment: yes, that worked. @Ipounng,Thank you for your help. Another thing I faced problem was if I pass a list of size >2500 geo location returns a none value,found that we can't call geolocator for list size more than 2500, any way to get around this?

Comment: that depends on *why* geolocator does not allow size > 2500. Maybe it is restricted by the API, maybe other reason - check the documentation. How about reducing the list to <2500 and make multiple calls?